# Adding the letters of the alphabet to the string in order

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, list, char

I have a alphabet, like: *ABCDEFGHILJKLMN*

And i have a string like: *[https://test.com/c={here}](https://test.com/c=%7Bhere%7D)*

I want to add the above letters to the end of this string, respectively, where it says here.

Example:

- https://test.com/c=A
- https://test.com/c=B
- https://test.com/c=C

I wrote a code like this:

```
class GetNames():
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://test.com/c="
        self.new_url = []
        self.letters = ['A','B','C','Ç','D','E','F','G','H','I','İ','J','K','L','M','N','O',
                        'Ö','P','R','S','T','Ş','U','Ü','V','Y','Z']

    def get_letter(self):
        index = 0
        while self.letters:
            self.url += self.letters[index]
            self.new_url.append(self.url)
            index += 1
            if index == 28:
                break

        print(self.new_url)
```

I get output like this:

- https://test.com/c=A
- https://test.com/c=AB
- https://test.com/c=ABC

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert this line add the first of while loop like below:

```
self.url = "https://test.com/c="
```

finally code:

```
class GetNames():
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://test.com/c="
        self.new_url = []
        self.letters = ['A','B','C','Ç','D','E','F','G','H','I','İ','J','K','L','M','N','O',
                        'Ö','P','R','S','T','Ş','U','Ü','V','Y','Z']

    def get_letter(self):
        index = 0
        while self.letters:
            self.url = "https://test.com/c="
            self.url += self.letters[index]
            self.new_url.append(self.url)
            index += 1
            if index == 28:
                break

        print(self.new_url)
```

output:

```
['https://test.com/c=A', 'https://test.com/c=B', 'https://test.com/c=C', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

After self.url += self.letters[index]
self.new_url.append(self.url)

make sure to add this line: self.url="https://test.com/c="

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks complicated, you can use for loops instead of while

```py
class GetNames:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'http://test.com/c='
        self.new_url = []
        self.letters = ['A','B','C','Ç','D','E','F','G','H','I','İ','J','K','L','M','N','O',
                        'Ö','P','R','S','T','Ş','U','Ü','V','Y','Z']

    def get_letter(self):
        for i in range(28):
            self.new_url.append(self.url + self.letters[i])

a = GetNames()
a.get_letter()
print(a.new_url)
```

Output

```py
['http://test.com/c=A', 'http://test.com/c=B', ... , 'http://test.com/c=Y', 'http://test.com/c=Z']
```